# Помогите с заданием. Есть задание и его нужно реализовать с помощью двух методов. У меня возникают ошибки и я не знаю, как их исправить

Tags: java

Основное задание: превратить String, представляющий собой число в шестнадцатеричной системе счисления, в значение int. Проблема со строкой 
if (s<0) {throw new IllegalArgumentException(" Parametr s: " + s + " is not suitable!");}

```
class HexStringToInt {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       printRes("CAFE");
       printRes("0");
       printRes("9");
       printRes("10");
    }

    public static int hexStringToInt(String s){
        int res = 0;
        res = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(s), 16);
        return res;
        if (s<0){
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(" Parametr s: " + s + " is not suitable!");
        }
    }

    static void printRes(String s) {
        System.out.print("k:" + s + " result: ");
        try {
            System.out.println(hexStringToInt(s));
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException var5) {
            System.out.println("EXCEPTION!" + var5.getMessage());
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: 1. В чем проблема? 2. Кратко опишите вашу конкретную проблему в заголовке.

Answer (score 0):

вот работает:

```
package com.company;

class HexStringToInt {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        printRes("CAFE");
        printRes("0");
        printRes("9");
        printRes("10");
        printRes("-32");
    }

    public static int hexStringToInt(String s){
        int res = 0;
        res = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(s), 16);
        if (res<0){
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(" Parametr s: " + s + " is not suitable!");
        }
        return res;
    }

    static void printRes(String s) {
        System.out.print("k:" + s + " result: ");
        try {
            System.out.println(hexStringToInt(s));
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException var5) {
            System.out.println("EXCEPTION!" + var5.getMessage());
        }

    }
}
```